# Xamarin Studio on OS X says namespace couldn't be found, but it's definitely there?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin

I'm fairly new to Xamarin Studio, so I expect this to be a relatively simple question.

I have a solution with multiple projects in it. 1 of them is a library, 1 of them an application. The application references the library and adds it as a reference, then attempts to use it in code.

On the `using` keyword, it says that the namespace can't be found, while it definitely is there. If I type in `using NetSp`, Xamarin Studio is able to autocomplete just fine, so it definitely knows that it exists. What could be the problem?

[image]

See screenshot.

**Edit**: If I create a test project and a test library, I can't seem to reproduce this problem. The project in question is initially developed in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows, which I am trying to import into Xamarin Studio on Mac.

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference and re-adding it?  Or restarting XS?  I occasionally have problems with XS not picking up references from external libs, and restarting and/or doing a clean then build often fixes it.

Comment: I would check if the library set to build in the iOS configuration. Solution Options -> Build -> Configurations -> Configuration Mappings

Comment: please file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com